# Radio button group has value in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firefox, radio-button

I have an HTML form like

```html
    <form name="radio-mc">
        <input type="radio" name="mc" id="radio-1" value="1"> First
        <input type="radio" name="mc" id="radio-2" value="2"> Second
        <input type="radio" name="mc" id="radio-3" value="3"> Third
    </form>
```

I can get the selected value in Chrome by form/input name with the following javascript

```js
document.forms['radio-mc']['mc'].value
```

But in Firefox, the value is undefined.

I would normally think this was a specialty of Chrome but in the Firefox inspector I can see that parent object is an `[object NodeList]` that has a `value` property. It's simply not set to anything... seemingly ever.

I cannot use jQuery in this situation. Is there any way to get that one value in vanilla javascript in Firefox (without iterating over the radio buttons like I can in Chrome)?

Comment: try this
var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='mc']:checked");

Comment: Do you need to support IE8 and lower? If not, then `document.forms['radio-mc'].querySelector('input:checked');`

Comment: @cookiemonster I do not. That worked wonderfully. Thank you!

Comment: @cookiemonster you should post that as an answer

Comment: @kennypu: Thanks, but RobG gave a much more detailed answer than I would have, so I think I'll just +1 his. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to the introduction of the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/), the only way to get the value of a radio button group was to iterate over the members:

```
function getRadioValue(group) {
  for (var i=0, iLen=group.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (group[i].checked) {
      return group[i].value;
    }
  }
  // No button selected - return '' or undefined?
  return '';
}

console.log(getRadioValue(document.forms['radio-mc']['mc'])); // value
```

However, as *cookie monster* commented, you can use *querySelectorAll* for browsers that support it:

```
var checked = document.forms['radio-mc'].querySelector('input:checked');
console.log(checked? checked.value : '');
```

If you have more than one set of radio buttons in the form, or also have checkboxes, you'll need something like:

```
document.forms['radio-mc'].querySelector('[name=mc]:checked')
```

otherwise you'll just get the first checked radio or checkbox.

Also, since you don't have a default selected button, you need to handle the case where no button is selected.